# spacebar is not working in input and textarea

Tags: comments

i have displayed comments box with `<?php comments_template(); ?>` and now when i am styling the `input` and `textarea`. Surprisingly both are not allowing spacebar. That means when i type something in `input` and `textarea` and hit spacebar it doesn't reflect the space in there.!

Can someone help me out in the issue?

Comment: What style do you use for styling input and textarea?

Comment: i am just applying basic rules to textarea and input through css. That's it.! And now i figured out that i have kept `<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>` in `<base/>` tag. like this `<base href="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/">` is creating problems for me.